# jQuery autocomplete deactivates bootstrap menu dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I am using twitter bootstrap as my site framework. I am also using jQuery.

In my main navigation bar I have a bootstrap dropdown that contains a search box. The search box has a jQuery autocomplete function that works perfectly.

My problem however is that when the user clicks on one of the items in the autocomplete list the bootstrap dropdown closes preventing the user from clicking the "search" button until they re-open the dropdown (The search query is still present).

Obviously this is annoying my users...

Is there an easy way to prevent the dropdown from closing when a selection is made from the autocomplete list? Is this due to a conflict between the two frameworks?

[image: Auto Complete]

Thanks in advance.

Gordon

UPDATE:

Solved this with the below code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('body').find('.ui-autocomplete').click(function (e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
               });
            });
    </script>
```

This stops the propagation on the ui-autocomplete dropdown element when clicked on and keeps the bootstrap dropdown open to allow users to click the search button.

Thanks to isherwood for the pointer

Answer (score 1):

It's not a conflict, but the normal behavior for Bootstrap's menu. I use these functions for that purpose:

```
$(function() {
    //prevent menu from closing when clicking into a form element
    $('.drop').find('form').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // other elements with the 'stay-open' class
    $('.drop').find('.stay-open').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Where to I add the .stay-open class? On the textbox? <asp:TextBox ID="NavBarSearchItemNo" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="input-medium search-query stay-open" Placeholder="Part No" />

Comment: That, or one of its ancestors. Chances are the first example will take care of it for you, assuming the form tag is inside the menu dropdown.

Comment: Hmmm, not getting any joy from that. I have the <script> block at the end of the page just before the </body> tag. Does this need to be in the <head> or something?

Comment: Do you have it wrapped in document.ready? http://api.jquery.com/ready (See updated answer.)

Comment: Yeah, although I'm the first to admit JS is not my forte

Comment: Here it is with Bootstrap working. You'll need to convert some of your ASP code to HTML for a proper demo.